# While dragging a div, move another div together with the dragged div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Two divs are present in different containers.
I want to move the **div1** in **container1** while dragging **div2** in **container2**.
(the 'left' property should remain same for div1 and div2 at all times)

I am able to individually drag each of them by applying '**draggable**' function.
Also I am able to move the **div2** while movie **div1** by assigning the **left** property of **div1** to the **left** property of **div2** while 'draggable stop' function is called. 
But this happens only when after the drag event is finished.

Is there a way so that the div2 will move together with div1 all the time while dragging div1?

**Please refer to the JSFiddle link to understand what I am trying to do :**
http://jsfiddle.net/37Wkd/16/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#block1').draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    containment: '#container1',
    drag: function(){
        $('#block2').css('left',$(this).position().left);  
    }

});​
```

Doesn't this work?
Using the `drag` event:  http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/37Wkd/17/